# How do I configure my eero mesh router to allow incoming connections to my full bitcoin node?

Tags: router, bitcoin

I have a raspberrypi 4B with an external 1TB SSD running a full bitcoin node (v22.0.0). IBD is complete (and has been for a couple of days). I've followed all setup instructions [here](https://bitcoin.org/en/full-node#network-configuration) (IP reservation, port forwarding, no firewall on the rpi, etc.) but still cannot see any incoming connections. Neither, according bitode.io, is my node reachable.

My router is an eero running v6.9.2-1. Having triple-checked that my rpi's IP is properly reserved and port 8333 is properly set up to forward, what else do I need to check?

TIA

Comment: Maybe you are behind CGNAT?

Comment: Does your ISP allow you to host services such as this? Most mobile providers block such traffic and some landlines providers do as well.

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/1168767/incoming-port-blocking-by-isp is what Tom Yan is talking about.

Answer (score 0):

OK I figured this out. We recently upgraded our internet to 1GB; I didn't realize the ISP's box was both modem AND router. So I had to set up port forwarding from the ISP-provided modem/router to the eero, then from eero to the raspberrypi. Once I did that, my node was reachable and I saw incoming connections.

Thanks to the responders above.